# Payment request from user to site

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, paypal

I'm developing an app now that will give prizes for the user according to some rules.

The thing is I want to make use of PayPal or any other payment service to allow the user to accumulate some prizes and then request me the payment. Is that possible or I can use PayPal and similars only to Pay someone actively/manually ?

Answer (score 0):

Automating PayPal transactions should be possible with their SDK - check the docs here: [PayPal Developer](https://developer.paypal.com), specifically [Payouts](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts/).

But first of all, I think you should consider **your own** interest. From my experience, fully automating this kind of transactions puts you in a risk of losing the money to fraud.

I would advise creating some kind of buffer, an admin dashboard where you will see all the payout requests from users, be able to verify them and then reject or approve the payment. This verification step could be automated further in the future with some bot or AI (eg [SiftScience)](https://siftscience.com/)